Function with subtype argument doesn't cast to a function with a base type argument
I'm trying to implement a middleware for Koa that slightly extends type of state on context, but the extended state doesn't cast successfully to the base state if I try to cast function that uses extended state to a function that uses base state. I've spent 3 hours already figuring out what is wrong, but I still don't understand.
I've made the smallest reproducible sample:
type A = {
  foo: number
}

type B = A & {
  bar: number
}

type FuncA = (middie: A) => void
type FuncB = (middie: B) => void

const fa = {} as FuncA
const fb = {} as FuncB
const fc: FuncA = fb // doesn't work

So the last row complains that bar doesn't exist on A, but I'm trying to cast extended version of A to A (base version), which should logically be fine since all props on A exist on B. But for some reason TS made it wise versa which is not what I expect.
Casting B to A itself, without a function, works correctly, so I think there is something to do with how TS works with function arguments?
Playground: click

The type checker is correct. If you could assign a function that expects a B to a function type that takes an A, then you would be able to call it with an A that is not a B, which would likely result in type errors at runtime when the function accesses the bar property.

@TimMoore wow, that's true. Now everything is understandable! Would you be ok posting an answer?

The type checker is correct. To see why, it might help to use some more concrete examples of FuncA and FuncB:
const fa = (a: A) => console.log(`A ${a.foo.toString()}`)
const fb = (b: B) => console.log(`B: ${b.foo.toString()}, ${b.bar.toString()}`)

(I know that the toString() calls are unnecessary in this context, but they're just to illustrate a dereference of the properties of A and B.)
If const fc: FuncA = fb were allowed, it would also have to allow you to call fc with a parameter that is an A, but not a B. This results in a runtime error when trying to dereference bar.
fc({ foo: 123 }) // [ERR]: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.bar.toString') 

On the other hand, reversing this is completely safe:
const fd: FuncB = fa // This is fine
fd({ foo: 123, bar: 456 }) // [LOG]: "A 123" 

Again, it makes intuitive sense when you think about it in concrete terms: B satisfies the requirements of A by having a foo field, so functions that require an A can accept a B.
Return types work in the opposite direction:
type FuncE = () => A;
type FuncF = () => B;

const fe = () => ({ foo: 123 });
const ff = () => ({ foo: 345, bar: 678 });
const fg: FuncE = ff; // This is fine
const fh: FuncF = fe; // Type '() => { foo: number; }' is not assignable to type 'FuncF'.

This follows the same reasoning: a function that produces a valid B is also producing a valid A, but not the other way around.
Note that this behaviour in TypeScript is controlled by the strictFunctionTypes compiler option (which is automatically enabled by the more general strict option). If necessary, this can be disabled, but with the caveat that it will allow unsafe uses.
Another way to think about these types is from the perspective of Generics and type parameters:
type Func<T, R> = (middie: T) => R;
type FuncA1 = Func<A, void>;
type FuncB1 = Func<B, void>;
type FuncE1 = Func<void, A>;
type FuncF1 = Func<void, B>;

The way that supertype/subtype relationships are handled between a generic type and its parameters is known as variance, and is described in great detail in the answers to Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript.
To sum up briefly, given that B is a subtype of A, for a generic type type G<T>:

If G<B> is a subtype of G<A>, G is said to be covariant with respect to T.
If G<B> is a supertype of G<A>, G is said to be contravariant with respect to T.
If G<A> and G<B> have no supertype/subtype relationship, G is said to be invariant with respect to T.
If G<A> and G<B> are fully interchangeable, G is said to be bivariant with respect to T. This is rarely safe, but is the default behaviour when strictFunctionTypes is disabled.

From this, we can say that functions in TypeScript (with strictFunctionTypes enabled) are covariant with respect to their return types and contravariant with respect to their parameter types.
Expanded Playground Link
